# MongoDB data not being displayed

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, echo

I have a mongoDB collection named **order**. I am trying to get all order details for the customer currently logged in. I am using the customers email as reference to the logged in user. This line, echo "email is ".$email; displays the email correctly. However I am unable to display other data. Can you help me please?

```
<?php
$mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $mongoClient->commerce;

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo "email is ".$email;
$findCriteria = [
     ["customer_email" => $email] 
];
$cursor = $db->order->find($findCriteria);
echo "<h1>Order History</h1>";
foreach ($cursor as $ord) {
     $email = $ord['customer_email'];
    /*  $price = $cust['cost'];   
     $products = $cust['products'];*/
      echo "test";
     echo "email is ".$email;
   /*echo "<br>";
   echo "email is ".$price;
   echo "<br>";
   echo "email is ".$products;
   echo "<br>";  */ 
}
```

[order collection on mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWjH3.png)

Comment: TryThis $cursor = $db->Order->find({"customer_email":$email});

Comment: hello sir. The line is causing a syntax error

Comment: Try This, $findCriteria = array("customer_email" => $email);

Comment: @teddy the `$findCriteria` content should be `["customer_email" => $email]` not `["email" => $email]`

Comment: I changed it to the code above. but it is still not working

Comment: @Neodan please help me. I have been stuck for a few days. please, I really need your help